# BehaviourSubject not return the updated data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to access the updated data on Resolver. But the behaviourSubject not returned updated Data.

Here is how I did:

ConfigService.ts (Holds the config values)

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
 constructor() { }
 getAnsweredJsonObj() {
    const isMC =  false;
    const jsonObject = {
      country_code: 'US',
      language: 'en',
      height_inches: {foot: undefined, inches: undefined},
      goals: {},
      guest: (!isMC) ? true : false
    };
    return jsonObject;
  }
}
```

QuestionsService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionsService {

 private answeredSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.configService.getAnsweredJsonObj());

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  getAnsweredSubject(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.answeredSubject.asObservable();
  }

  setAnsweredSubject(answered) {
    this.answeredSubject.next(answered);
  }
}
```

FormComponent.ts (Update the behaviourSubject value from component)

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private questionsService: QuestionsService) {}

    getResults() {
      const answered = {
          country_code: "US",
          language: "en",
          height_inches: 87,
          goals: [
              "WEIGHT",
              "PERFORMANCE",
              "AGING"
          ],
          guest: true
      };
      this.questionsService.setAnsweredSubject(answered);
      this.router.navigate(['/healthprint-results']);
  }
```

BundlesResolver.ts (Use latest formComponent data here)

```
@Injectable()
export class BundlesResolver implements Resolve <any> {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private questionService: QuestionsService) {}

    resolve (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any>{
        this.questionService.getAnsweredSubject().subscribe((value) => {
            console.log("Subscription got", value); // not printing the updated value
            this.answered = value;
        });

        return this.http.post('/services/getBundles', this.answered)
            .map(responseData => {
            console.log('responseData', responseData);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps using rxjs? If so, you may want to [edit] to add the tag for that to your question.

Comment: The first thing to note is that your `.map(responseData => {})` needs to `return responseData`,

Comment: Or if you just want to log it there, change `.map(responseData => { console.log(responseData) }` to `.do(responseData => { console.log(responseData) }`, since `do` will automatically return the responseData.

Comment: Form component is never closed, and `getResults()` is never called.